# Kann man deutsche Grammatik nachträglich lernen?

Tags: grammar

Ich bin deutschsprachig -im Ausland- aufgewachsen. Da meine Frau Ausländerin ist, stellt sie mir ständig Fragen, warum dies so oder so gesagt wird. Ich kann ihr mit einiger Mühe doch erklären, warum es nur auf diese Weise gesagt wird oder auf jene Weise besser klingt. Nur fehlt mir dann und wann halt eine grammatikalische Erklärung. Mich würde es interessieren, ob man auf einfache Weise sich das eine oder andere aus der deutschen Grammatik gewissermaßen nachträglich erarbeiten kann und ob es dazu auch Literatur oder dergleichen gibt!

Comment: Klar kann man - und machen auch viele. Jede gute Buchhandlung sollte Schulgrammatiken haben. Da gibt es auch ganz hübsche mit Übungen zum Verständnis, nicht nur "trockene" Nachschlagewerke. Und für alle anderen Fälle sind wir ja auch noch da ;-)

Comment: Das machen nicht nur "viele", sondern fast "alle": kleine Kinder, die deutsch als Muttersprache lernen, werfen nicht vorher einen Blick in die Grammatik, bevor sie anfangen zu plappern, sondern erlernen sie auch erst nachträglich ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eigentlich lernen alle Muttersprachler die Grammatik ihrer eigenen Sprache nachträglich -- ob nun in der Schule, oder eben noch später.

Statt Büchern genügt auch das Internet (wenn man Bücher nicht prinzipiell vorzieht):

- [mein-deutschbuch.de](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/grammatik.html) hat eigentlich alles, was jemand, der Deutsch lernt, über die deutsche Grammatik wissen muss. Zum Lernen sehr geeignet; alles wird kurz aber klar erklärt. Nicht zu viel und nicht zu wenig.
- [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/) zum Nachschlagen, wenn es um wirklich komplizierte Dinge geht. Zum Lernen ist es zu umfangreich.

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde mir den großen Grammatikduden kaufen, da steht so ziemlich alles drin, was man über die deutsche Sprache wissen kann. Es wird Dir unter Umständen leichter fallen nachzuschlagen, was sie wissen möchte.

Der Duden kann aber auch nicht beantworten, warum etwas "besser klingt". Bestimmte Dinge "sind halt so" und auch regional und je nach Schicht unterschiedlich. Bestimmte Sachen wird sie mit der Zeit auch einfach durch Nachahmung von selbst lernen.

Comment: Ich finde alle bisherigen Antworten gut muss aber sagen, internet geht meist schneller als die richtige Regel im Duden zu finden